# Can you delete keys from a map in Golang using a variable that contains the name of the key instead of the key in quotations?

Tags: dictionary, go

**This is my code:**
package main

```
import "fmt"

var map1 = make(map[string]string)

func main() {

delete()

}

func delete() {

fmt.Println("Enter key to be deleted: ")
var key2 string
fmt.Scanln(&key2)

fmt.Println(map1)
for index, element := range map1 {
    if index == key2 {

        delete(map1, index)
        fmt.Println(map1)
    
    }
}
}
```

**This is the error message**

go:95:9: too many arguments in call to delete
have (map[string]string, string)
want ()

I'm trying to create a map where the program can delete items upon user input but it doesn't seem like I can pass a variable as an argument to the delete() function.
Is there any way to get around this?

Comment: rename your function.

Comment: Dont use predefined function names in your program as delete. surprise how go allows it and not throwing an error at delete()

Answer (score 4):

You named your function `delete`, so inside it you shadow the builtin [`delete()`](https://pkg.go.dev/builtin#delete) function, and using it will refer to your `delete()` function. Rename it.

Also note that to achieve what you want, you don't need a loop, just use `delete(map1, key2)`:

```
func remove() {
    fmt.Println("Enter key to be deleted: ")
    var key2 string
    fmt.Scanln(&key2)

    fmt.Println(map1)
    delete(map1, key2)
    fmt.Println(map1)
}
```